# PXAction doesn't want ot save Cache data

Tags: acumatica

Good day

Build 20.107.0026

Screen id FS300200

I have created a button on the Appointments screen that does some work and to calculate the long and Latitude of an address.

I have extended my Adress and added the usrDeliveryAddressLongitude & usrDeliveryAddressLattitude.

but for the life of me, I can't get this thing to save to the DB.

I have another button on the same screen and when I debug, the button references the above fields and can see that the data is there.

What is the correct way to save the AddressExt data in a button on the Appointments screen?

```
public PXSelect<
            Address,
            Where<Address.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>> Addresslist;

   
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.FS.FSAppointment> DoWork;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "DoWork")]
    protected void doWork()
    {
        try
        {
            FSServiceOrder curFSServiceOrder = Base.ServiceOrderRelated.Current;
            //check customerID
            BAccount curBAccount = PXSelect<
                BAccount,
                Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>
                .Select(Base, curFSServiceOrder.CustomerID);

            string DeliveryAddressLongitude = "";
            string DeliveryAddressLattitude = "";

            //DeliveryAddress
            Location curLocation = PXSelect<
                Location,
                Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>,
                    And<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<FSServiceOrder.locationID>>>>>
                .Select(Base, curBAccount.BAccountID, curFSServiceOrder.LocationID);

            Address curAddress = PXSelect<
                Address,
                Where<Address.addressID, Equal<Required<Location.defAddressID>>,
                    And<Address.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>>
                .Select(Base, curLocation.DefAddressID, curBAccount.BAccountID);

            //Removed code that is not needed
            DeliveryAddressLongitude = "fakeLong";
            DeliveryAddressLattitude = "fakeLant"; 

            // the below is a couple of things I have tried, i removed a couple of them that where 
            //   not working at all 


              Addresslist.SetValueExt<AddressExt.usrDeliveryAddressLongitude>(curAddress, DeliveryAddressLongitude);
              Addresslist.SetValueExt<AddressExt.usrDeliveryAddressLattitude>(curAddress, DeliveryAddressLattitude);

            

            AddressExt curAddressExt = PXCache<Address>.GetExtension<AddressExt>(curAddress);
            curAddressExt.UsrDeliveryAddressLattitude = DeliveryAddressLattitude;
            curAddressExt.UsrDeliveryAddressLongitude = DeliveryAddressLongitude;

            Addresslist.Update(curAddress);
            
            Base.Caches<Address>().Cached.
            //FSAppointment curFSAppointment = Base.AppointmentRecords.Current;
            //FSAppointmentExt curFSAppointmentExt = curFSAppointment.GetExtension<FSAppointmentExt>();
            // Base.
            //Addresslist.Update(curAddress);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PXTrace.WriteError(ex);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the above happens. Think it is because there is a address/location type in 2 places in the system. I opened a PXGraph for the customer location and saved the data using that. there is 2 ways to do that I show both below:

```
        CustomerLocationMaint customerLocationGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();

        customerLocationGraph.Address.SetValueExt<AddressExt.usrDeliveryAddressLongitude>(curAddress, DeliveryAddressLongitude);
        customerLocationGraph.Address.SetValueExt<AddressExt.usrDeliveryAddressLattitude>(curAddress, DeliveryAddressLattitude);

        AddressExt curAddressExt = PXCache<Address>.GetExtension<AddressExt>(curAddress);
        curAddressExt.UsrDeliveryAddressLattitude = DeliveryAddressLattitude;
        curAddressExt.UsrDeliveryAddressLongitude = DeliveryAddressLongitude;

        customerLocationGraph.Address.Update(curAddress);

        customerLocationGraph.Save.PressButton();
```